# summarise divide two columns as percent

Tags: r, dplyr, divide, summarize

I'm having trouble finding what percent of Canada geese get killed during migration season using the Airplane Strikes data set.

```
#airline stats table
airlines <- sd4 %>% 
group_by(STATE) %>% 
filter(SPECIES == "Canada goose" & total_kills > 1) %>% 
mutate(fall_mig_kills = ifelse(SPECIES=="Canada goose" & INCIDENT_MONTH %in% c(9,10,11),total_kills,0)) %>% 
summarise(
pct_mig_kills = fall_mig_kills/total_kills
) %>% 
select(STATE,SPECIES,INCIDENT_MONTH,total_kills,fall_mig_kills,pct_mig_kills)`
```

here is where i'm getting the error:
`summarise(
    pct_mig_kills = fall_mig_kills/total_kills
  )`

and the error is:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `pct_mig_kills` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 10
```

not sure how i'm getting a value longer than length 1 when dividing two integer columns.

any help would be appreciated!

Benjamin

Comment: We have no idea what `sd4` is.

Comment: When asking for help you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run and test the code. You are using ` group_by()` so it seems like each state probably has multiple records, but when you use `fall_mig_kills/total_kills` in `summarize()`, you'll get a value for each row, not a single summary value. If you want one value per state, you need to make it clear how you want to collapse values. Maybe `sum(fall_mig_kills)/sum(total_kills)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's read the data, document everything, and see where your error arises.

In general, you should have a link to your original dataset or provide a shortened version to follow the [reproducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility) principle. I found an [aircraft wildlife strikes, 1990-2015](https://www.kaggle.com/faa/wildlife-strikes/data) dataset on Kaggle, which I will be using here. ***Note:*** You will need to have a Kaggle account to download the data. It may also be available at [data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/aircraft-wildlife-strike-data-raw-data).

#### Read in Data

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.csv("~/../Downloads/database.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
> df$Species.Name[grepl("Canada goose", df$Species.Name, ignore.case = T)][1]
[1] "CANADA GOOSE"

> names(df)
 [1] "Record.ID"            "Incident.Year"        "Incident.Month"      
 [4] "Incident.Day"         "Operator.ID"          "Operator"            
 [7] "Aircraft"             "Aircraft.Type"        "Aircraft.Make"       
[10] "Aircraft.Model"       "Aircraft.Mass"        "Engine.Make"         
[13] "Engine.Model"         "Engines"              "Engine.Type"         
[16] "Engine1.Position"     "Engine2.Position"     "Engine3.Position"    
[19] "Engine4.Position"     "Airport.ID"           "Airport"             
[22] "State"                "FAA.Region"           "Warning.Issued"      
[25] "Flight.Phase"         "Visibility"           "Precipitation"       
[28] "Height"               "Speed"                "Distance"            
[31] "Species.ID"           "Species.Name"         "Species.Quantity"    
[34] "Flight.Impact"        "Fatalities"           "Injuries"            
[37] "Aircraft.Damage"      "Radome.Strike"        "Radome.Damage"       
[40] "Windshield.Strike"    "Windshield.Damage"    "Nose.Strike"         
[43] "Nose.Damage"          "Engine1.Strike"       "Engine1.Damage"      
[46] "Engine2.Strike"       "Engine2.Damage"       "Engine3.Strike"      
[49] "Engine3.Damage"       "Engine4.Strike"       "Engine4.Damage"      
[52] "Engine.Ingested"      "Propeller.Strike"     "Propeller.Damage"    
[55] "Wing.or.Rotor.Strike" "Wing.or.Rotor.Damage" "Fuselage.Strike"     
[58] "Fuselage.Damage"      "Landing.Gear.Strike"  "Landing.Gear.Damage" 
[61] "Tail.Strike"          "Tail.Damage"          "Lights.Strike"       
[64] "Lights.Damage"        "Other.Strike"         "Other.Damage"        
[67] "totalKills"
```

Notice that the species name is in ALL CAPITAL LETTERS. Use `grepl` instead of `==` unless you are certain you know the name verbatim.

There is no `total_kills` variable, and the `Fatalities` variable represents *human* fatalities, so I'm going to ignore that filter variable. What I did find was `Species.Quantity`, which is probably what you are looking for, the total number of species killed during an incident.

```
> unique(df$Species.Quantity)
[1] "1"        "2-10"     ""         "11-100"   "Over 100"
```

We can convert these values to numerics for this example.

```
> dictNames <- unique(df$Species.Quantity)
> dict <- c(1, 2, 0, 11, 100)
> names(dict) <- dictNames
> dict['1']
1 
1 
> dict['2-10']
2-10 
   2 
> df <- df %>% mutate(totalKills = dict[Species.Quantity])
> table(df$totalKills, useNA = "always")

     1      2     11    100   <NA> 
146563  21852   1166     46   4477
```

Great, now let's look at your code.

#### Try Out Your Code and Find the Issue

```
> df %>% 
+   group_by(State) %>% 
+   filter(Species.Name == "CANADA GOOSE" & totalKills > 1) %>% 
+   mutate(fall_mig_kills = ifelse(Species.Name == "CANADA GOOSE" & 
+                                    Incident.Month %in% c(9,10,11),
+                                  totalKills,
+                                  0)
+          ) %>% 
+   summarise(
+     pct_mig_kills = fall_mig_kills/totalKills
+   )
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `pct_mig_kills` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 19
```

Hmm, let's see why that is. Reading the help menu by typing in `?summarise` in the console says:

> summarise {dplyr} R Documentation Reduces multiple values down to a
>   single value
>
> Description
>
> summarise() is typically used on grouped data created by group_by().
>   The output will have one row for each group.

Okay, so the output will have **one row** for each **group.** Since you have grouped a variable, we need to **sum** the total kills. Furthermore, you may want to create a new variable "inSeason" which will allow you to summarise your data appropriately.

So, to fix your issue, you simply add in `sum`:

```
+   summarise(
+     pct_mig_kills = sum(fall_mig_kills)/sum(totalKills)
+   )
# A tibble: 49 x 2
   State pct_mig_kills
   <chr>         <dbl>
 1          0.70212766
 2    AK    0.50000000
 3    AL    0.00000000
 4    AR    1.00000000
 5    CA    0.06185567
```

#### Rewrite Your Code without Errors

Now let's change it to read slightly easier. And you care about **season**, not **state.**

```
> df %>%
+   # inSeason = seasons we care about monitoring
+   # totalKills has NA values, we choose to put deaths at 0
+   mutate(inSeason = ifelse(Incident.Month %in% 9:11, "in", "out"),
+          totalKills = ifelse(is.na(totalKills), 0, totalKills)) %>%
+   # canadian geese only
+   filter(grepl("canada goose", Species.Name, ignore.case = T)) %>%
+   # collect data by inSeason
+   group_by(inSeason) %>%
+   # sum them up
+   summarise(totalDead = sum(totalKills)) %>%
+   # add a ratio value
+   mutate(percentDead = round(100*totalDead/sum(totalDead),0))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  inSeason totalDead percentDead
     <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1       in       838          34
2      out      1620          66
```

Now you have in season versus out of season, total dead, and a percentage. If you want to add in state, add that variable into your groupings.

One other note, `group_by` with a `summarise` automatically removes the other columns, so you do not need to use `select` at the end.

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(inSeason = ifelse(Incident.Month %in% 9:11, "in", "out"),
+          totalKills = ifelse(is.na(totalKills), 0, totalKills)) %>%
+   filter(grepl("canada goose", Species.Name, ignore.case = T)) %>%
+   group_by(State, inSeason) %>%
+   summarise(totalDead = sum(totalKills)) %>%
+   mutate(percentDead = round(100*totalDead/sum(totalDead),0))
# A tibble: 98 x 4
# Groups:   State [51]
   State inSeason totalDead percentDead
   <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1             in        52          52
 2            out        48          48
 3    AB       in         1          50
 4    AB      out         1          50
 5    AK       in        13          33
 6    AK      out        26          67
 7    AL       in         2          40
 8    AL      out         3          60
 9    AR       in         6         100
10    CA       in        13           8
```

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable and thorough answer.  I'm new to Stack Overflow.  I will definitely follow all of your tips when posting questions in future.  I only provided part of the code, you're right.  I really appreciate this help!  I marked as answered since I didn't provide enough data.